# Какой использовать селектор, чтобы получить описание из трех указанных ссылок?

Tags: javascript, jquery, веб-программирование

Я хочу собрать статистику с сайта с вакансиями.
Мне нужно получить описание вакансии.

```
var cell = document.getElementsByClassName("vacancy-section");
console.log(cell[0].textContent);
```

Такой код работает на
[Первая ссылка](https://spb.hh.ru/vacancy/66834766?from=vacancy_search_list&hhtmFrom=vacancy_search_list&query=%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%20Java)
, но захватывает в том числе код на [Вторая ссылка](https://spb.hh.ru/vacancy/47759634?from=vacancy_search_list&hhtmFrom=vacancy_search_list&query=%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%20Java) или [Третья ссылка](https://spb.hh.ru/vacancy/53878752?from=vacancy_search_list&hhtmFrom=vacancy_search_list&query=%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%20Java)

Можете сказать, каким образом составить селектор, чтобы он мог взять текст сразу для трех ссылок?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На экране в элементе вы видите только текст и медиа, но в коде может быть что угодно.

- `.textContent` вернёт вам текст элемента и всех дочерних элементов, будь то `<script>`, `<style>` и т.п.
- `.innerText` вернёт текст того, что отображается на экране.
- Ну и стоит сказать о `.innerHTML`, который вернёт HTML код

```js
var text = document.querySelector('.text');

console.log('--- textContent ---');
console.log(text.textContent);

console.log('--- innerText ---');
console.log(text.innerText);

console.log('--- innerHTML ---');
console.log(text.innerHTML);
```

```html
<p class="text">
  Какой-то текст
  <br>
  <b styte="color: red;">Какой-то текст</b>
  <style>.text {background: linear-gradient(-135deg, transparent, #ccc)}</style>
</p>
```

Отличие [`.textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent) от [`.innerText`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent#%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%BE%D1%82_innertext) и от [`.innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent#%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%BE%D1%82_innerhtml)

---

В вашем случае, думаю, подойдёт `.innerText`, он вернёт только текст описания вакансии, без картинок и стилизации (жирный шрифт, выделения текста, маркированный список и т.п.).

Либо используйте `.innerHTML`, предварительно удалив лишнее (`<script>`, `<style>`, например).

Comment: Вы правы, благодарю